# best way to store numpy arrays in ascii files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bigdata

I often have processed numpy arrays that come as a result of lengthy computations. I need to use them elsewhere in calculations. I currently 'pickle' them and unpickle the files into variables as and when I need them.

I noticed for large data sizes (~1M data points), this is slow. I read elsewhere that pickling is not best way to store huge files. I would like to store and read them as ASCII files efficiently to load directly into a numpy array. What is the best way to do this?

say I have a 100k x 3 2D array in a variable 'a'. I want to store it in an ASCII file and load it into a numpy array variable 'b'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy has a range of [input and output methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html) that will do exactly what you are after.

One option would be `numpy.save`:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([1,2,3,4])
with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, my_array, allow_pickle=False)
```

To load your data again:

```
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    my_loaded_array = np.load(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want efficiency, ASCII will not be the case. The problem with pickle is that it is dependent on the python version, so it's not a good idea for long term storage. You can try to use other binary technologies, where the most straightforward solution would be to use the `numpy.save` method as documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save).

Answer (score 2):

The problem you pose is directly related to the size of the dataset.

There are several solutions to this quite common problem that come with specialized libraries.

1. Python-only persistence: joblib offers an [alternative to pickle](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/persistence.html) specifically for storing files that are too large for convenient pickling.
2. HDF5 is a file format that is specifically targeted for storing arrays. The format is multi-language and multi-platform but a very good Python library exists for it: [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/)

An example with h5py. To write the data:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('data.h5', 'w') as f:
    f.create_dataset('a', data=a)
```

To read the data:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('data.h5', 'r') as f:
    b = f['a'][:]
```

Comment: I think hdf5 seems to be the right Option for my application. Since my question was to store in ASCII files (I meant human readable) I accepted the np.save option as answer. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the mention. I hope others will also find it useful, even though they would be looking for ascii storage :-)