# Saving a numpy array in ascii format

Tags: python, numpy, ascii

I have data in form of a 2D array.

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

How can I save the data as an ascii-file?

Furthermore: Is it problematic if the array contains a large amount of data?

I know how to save as data as a txt file, but that is not what I want or at least I would need to change the settings somehow.

Comment: This is a case where Google would have been faster than waiting for this list.  Numpy has a `savetxt` method.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html   If you need a very specific format, then you will need to do the writing on your own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [best way to store numpy arrays in ascii files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465547/best-way-to-store-numpy-arrays-in-ascii-files)

Comment: The '2d' row/column format of a CSV is the simplest and most common way saving and reading arrays.   After all, ascii files are inherently 2d - rows of lines. Writing higher dimensions is not as standardized.  It's much more application dependent.  Other file types are better for large arrays, and sets of arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `np.savetxt` function for that. For loading the text file, you can use `np.loadtxt`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
np.savetxt('saved_array.txt', a)

b = np.loadtxt('saved_array.txt')
print(a == b) # validation step
```

Alternatively, you can also just write a printable representational string into a text file using regular built-in python IO

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

with open('saved_array.txt', 'w') as fl:
    fl.write(repr(a))
```

Comment: I down voted because `fl.write(repr(a))` is almost always a totally unreasonable alternative

Comment: The `repl` can't be parsed dirwctly to recover the array.  And for large enough arrays, values will be missing.